# Adding values inside function to an empty string outside of a function

Tags: python, string, function, concatenation

```
empty_string = ''
string_1 = 'beta'

def sample(x):
    empty_string = empty_string + 'alpha'
    return x
```

why doesn't:

```
empty_string = 'alpha'
```

i'm confused why `empty_string` is still empty after i add to it in the function

Comment: @Ashwini's answer is good, however, it's usually better to make string functions return a new string, and the caller can update variables if they want. So `def alphaize(s): return s + 'alpha'` and then outside the function `empty_string = alphaize('foo')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `global empty_string` inside function, then only you can modify a global variable:

```
def sample(x):
    global empty_string
    empty_string = empty_string + 'alpha'
    return x
```